# Gridview controls disabled in rowdatabound but not showing same setting later

Tags: gridview, textbox, c#-2.0

I am disabling a `TextBox` in the gridview` based on some condition.

Later, while I am traversing the `griview`, when I check the TextBox.Enabled property, it is displaying as true. however I had set it to false for that row.

This code is within the rowdatabound event
I am just posting the code relevant to the problem

TextBox txt_location = (TextBox)e.Row.Cells[htDGV_Map["Trailer's Last Location"]].FindControl("txt_location");

string remark_status = "";
string status = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "SHIP_TRAIL_STATUS"));

if (status.Equals("L"))
     remark_status = "REMARK_POSTMARCH";
 else
     remark_status = "REMARK_REACH";

if (remark_status.Equals("REMARK_REACH"))
                {
                    txt_location.ReadOnly = true;
                }

Later I am trying to access the value of this property

```
TextBox txt_loc =

(TextBox)Gridrow.Cells[htDGV_Map["Tracking Trailers
Locations"]].FindControl("txt_location");
```

if(txt_loc.ReadOnly == true)
{
  // other code
}
Here the property comes as false, although I am expecting it to be true.

I tried to use the `ReadOnly` property of `TextBox`, but even here the `ReadOnly` property was found to be false, when I was expecting it to be true.

Comment: can u post the code here?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be aware of when applying custom settings for controls in the RowDataBound event is that if the page does a PostBack, unless you rebind the GridView, the custom settings will be lost.

Possible work arounds would be to either ensure that you always rebind the GridView on every PostBack or alternatively apply the Enabled / ReadOnly setting in the PreRender event, iterating through the DataRows, but you would also then need to store SHIP_TRAIL_STATUS somewhere (hidden field) during RowDataBound so that you could get access to it in PreRender - the ViewState would ensure that the value stored would remain static during PostBack's.